# Implement onClick Listener in Custom BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have a list view of ticket items with multiple columns.  I'm trying to figure out how to implement an onclick listener with what I've written.

Fragment_OpenTickets.java:

```
public class Fragment_OpenTickets extends Fragment {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ticketList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Context context = getActivity();
    DBController dbc = new DBController(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_opentickets, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.openList);
    Cursor cursor = dbc.getAllOpenTickets();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            int size = cursor.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                hashMap.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));
            }
            ticketList.add(hashMap);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    Adapter_OpenList adapter = new Adapter_OpenList(ticketList, context);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    dbc.close();

    return view;
}
}
```

Adapter_OpenList.java:

```
public class Adapter_OpenList extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ticketList;
Context context;
LayoutInflater mInflater;

public Adapter_OpenList(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr, Context c){
    ticketList = arr;
    context = c;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ticketList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ticketList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_openticket_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTicketNo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_ticketNo);
        holder.txtTicketDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_ticketDate);
        holder.txtLease = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_lease);
        holder.txtDelivLoc = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_delivLoc);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    HashMap map = ticketList.get(position);
    holder.txtTicketNo.setText((CharSequence) map.get("ticketNo"));
    holder.txtTicketDate.setText((CharSequence) map.get("ticketDate"));
    holder.txtLease.setText((CharSequence) map.get("lease"));
    holder.txtDelivLoc.setText((CharSequence) map.get("delivLoc"));

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTicketNo;
    TextView txtTicketDate;
    TextView txtLease;
    TextView txtDelivLoc;
}
}
```

If the user taps on a ticket row in the list I need to get the SQLite id of the ticket to either view it or start the ticket.  I know there are different ways to do this, but I'm just trying to get the basics down so I can play with it.  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I solved this by using code provided by Johan and removing a button I had in the fragment_openticket_row.xml file the adapter was using.  It was conflicting with the onClick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy approach is to create an ItemClickListener in your createView method like so :

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
            //Here you can get the position and access your 
            //TicketList Object
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, Johan, but I've ventured down this road too.  The only way I can get the IDE to accept the code is to use AdapterView like listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener().  Then in the onItemClick method I use System.out.println("TEST ") just to see if it's working.

Comment: I should have added that the code works with AdapterView, but nothing happens.

Comment: I had to manually import import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener; to make your code work.  It still does nothing when I click a row in the list.  I put the code in Fragment_OpenTickets.java just above dbc.close();

Comment: can you try for the context set to the view.getContext(); instead of getActivity();

Comment: android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener is the right import. Do you have any blocking views in the xml?

Comment: I got it!  I had a "Start" button in the XML file for each row.  That was the custom row I made for the adapter, thinking I was going to use a Start button for each ticket.  Thank you for all your help, Johan.  What do I need to do to close this thread or anything?

Comment: thats good, so it was a blocking ui element...to close it you can accept the answer so others will read this through and might help

Comment: Also its good practise if you edit your post with an update that the problem was XML related caused by a blocking button in each row.